# Android animation using coding or xml.i dont want to use any images for that animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I want the below GIF image using native animation code or XML. 
The attached image is sample image. I want that exact animation without using any other images.
[here is link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBgXn.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries which you can use for displaying gif images inside android application
but if you want to implement it by yourself you should use Drawable Animation which has been made for displaying some drawable sequentialy .

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html